# Do I need a transit visa In Casablanca Airport?

Tags: transit-visas, morocco, syrian-citizens, casablanca, cmn

I am travelling from Montreal (Canada) to Beirut (Lebanon) and transiting in Casablanca Airport (Morocco) for 8 hours. I currently hold a valid Canadian entry visa and study permit. My passport is Syrian. Do I need a Moroccan transit visa?

Answer (score 4):

Is your transit more or less than 24 hours? If it's not more, then you won't need a transit visa.

[Source](http://www.travel-exploration.com/page.cfm/Visa_Requirements):

Visas To Morocco: Required by all except the following:
Nationals of countries shown in the chart above for stays of up to 3 months;
Nationals of Andorra, Argentina, Bahrain, Brazil, Chile, Congo (Rep), Côte d'Ivoire, Guinea, Hungary, Iceland, Indonesia, Korea (Rep), Kuwait, Libya, Liechtenstein, Mali, Malta, Mexico, Monaco, Niger, Norway, Oman, Peru, Philippines, Puerto Rico, Qatar, Romania, Saudi Arabia, Senegal, Singapore, Switzerland, Tunisia, Turkey, United Arab Emirates and Venezuela for stays of up to three months. **Transit passengers continuing their journey by the same or first connecting aircraft within 24 hours provided holding onward or return documentation and not leaving the airport**.