# Do I need a transit visa in Morocco to travel from Egypt to Spain through Morocco?

Tags: transit-visas, morocco, egyptian-citizens

I am traveling by Royal Air Maroc and i am only staying for 5 hours in Casablanca airport during the trip from Cairo to Barcelona,and 3 hours only during the returning from Barcelona to Cairo and I'm Egyptian.

Comment: The Question was marked as duplicate. I Think it's not a duplicate because the author is traveling From Egypt to Spain, and the duplicated post's author was traveling from Canada to Lebanon. The two contexts are completly different as it depends on the nationality of the passanger to determine if you need a Visa or not, even if you are not entring to the country (Example: A moroccan who is transiting in the USA will need a Visa).

Answer (score 0):

If you're not leaving the airport, you don't need a visa.  Someone asked the same question two years ago:
[Do I need a Transit Visa In Casablanca Airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39692/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-in-casablanca-airport)